# Initializing 'MobileAds.initialize' on frequently visited home activity?

Tags: java, android, admob

Note: I've seen this: 'What is the proper way to call MobileAds.initialize()?' but am asking a different question.

I'm implementing AdMob inside of my application, and I see per Google's notes to add '`MobileAds.initialize(this, "app id");`' once for faster ad performance. I put this call inside of my `onCreate` method of the first activity that is displayed, but I am wondering if there are any issues with doing this as per usage of the app, the user may navigate back to this activity multiple times and '`MobileAds.initialize(...)`' will keep being initialised over and over.

Is this still okay, or can any issues be expected? Or would it be better to implement a splash screen on start in which this is done? Or could it be even better to not even use initialize?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid initialisation every time Use Application class onCreate() method

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

// ...

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), myAppId);
}
}
```

Comment: After we have initialised MobileAds in Application subclass, do we need to call it in our activities? Example is Google Analytic https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#application , they call AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication(); mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker(); in activity.

Comment: @user2872856 they don't call MobileAds anymore https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/admob/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/admobexample/kotlin/MainActivity.kt p.s. Ads has nothing to do with Analytics

Answer (score 1):

When the user navigates back to an `Activity`, the method `onCreate` is not called. Rather `onResume` is called.

So if you initialize ads inside the `onCreate` method of `MainActivity`, it will be initialized only once, and you are good to go.

Comment: this is wrong if you have not enough free memory and android decides to throw  MainActivity out of memory or after screen rotation.

Comment: I believe Google's developers are smart enough to reuse already initialized objects and handle such situations.